# UFT Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, hp-uft

Now I'm Currently Using UFT developer 15.1.0 trail Version, Also I have Configured with eclipse IDE, But Most of the feature not appeared. Eg. How can create "**Object Repository**" and **Data Driven** How i can read excel data. So please help me come out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

UFT has two different testing tools. UFT Develope (previously known as LeanFT) is developer oriented and can use Java with Eclipse. UFT One (previously just known as UFT) which is tester oriented and has object repository and supports data driven tests. It seems you're expecting UFT One's features from UFTD.

Comment: Thank you for your Clarification. Now I changed into UFT_one Testing Tool, I have not much idea in VB scripting language, I know Java only, any possiblity run through java....

Comment: No @mohamed, UFT One is vbscript only. However tests should be rather simple, you don't need to learn the language. By recording you can create a test with no vbs knowledge whatsoever